# Should I use Zend_Form?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm studying Zend Framework now and I think generating forms with programming is awkward and new to me.

The strength of using Zend_form is that it can be used with Zend Framework Form Validator.

What If I use manually generated forms with manually handled form validator?

Which one is better to use?

Especially in MVC style of work.

Web designer might not be familiar with Zend_Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think manual code is good solution rater than use zf commands. (Create zend forms)
Zend form is difficult for beginners. But finally it is easy than html form. 
Refer following documents.

Zend Form - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html

Zend Validators - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html

Answer (score 1):

I use Zend_forms pretty much the same way as described by Jason Gimore: http://www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/how_i_learned_to_stop_worrying_and_love_zend_form

This is the easiest way that i've found.